# Когда нужно использовать return в рекурсии, а когда нет?

Tags: c, рекурсия

**Вот пример:**
Задача рекурсивной функции проверить если левая цифра **n1** равна левой цифре **n2**, в случае если да, вернуть **1**, иначе вернуть **0**;

**В начале я решил так:**

```
int what(int n1, int n2)
{
    if (n1 < 10 && n2 < 10)
        return n1 == n2;
    if (n1 < 10)
        return what(n1, n2 / 10);
    if (n2 < 10)
        return what(n1 / 10, n2);
    return what(n1 / 10, n2 / 10);
}
```

Потом, когда проверял, увидел решение без **return**:

```
int what(int n1, int n2)
{
    if (n1 < 10 && n2 < 10)
        return n1 == n2;
    if (n1 < 10)
        return what(n1, n2 / 10);
    if (n2 < 10)
        return what(n1 / 10, n2);
    what(n1 / 10, n2 / 10);
}
```

**Почему это работает?**

И **почему** нельзя написать этот кусок кода без **return**?

```
if (n1 < 10)
        return what(n1, n2 / 10);
    if (n2 < 10)
        return what(n1 / 10, n2);
```

**Спасибо всем!**

Comment: Это не работает. Компилятор вас предупреждает что функция должна вернуть целое число но ничего не возвращает: "error: control reaches end of non-void function".

Comment: @Алексей, [укажите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1457300/edit) метку языка программирования в вопросе.

Comment: В подобных вопросах всегда указывайте ОС и версию компилятора.

Answer (score 4):

Работает, потому-что *случайно* возвращаемое значение, которое передавалась через регистры процессора не испортилось. Компилятору пока-что разрешается только выводить предупреждения, но стандарт дописывается, чтобы выводить уже ошибку.

стандарт **C11**:

> A **return** statement with an expression *shall not appear* in a
> function whose return type is **void**. A return statement without an
> expression *shall* only appear in a function whose return type is
> **void**.

Оператор **return** с выражением *не должен* присутствовать в функции, возвращаемый тип которой является **void**. Оператор возврата без выражения *должен* отображаться только в функции, возвращаемый тип которой является **void**.

стандарт **C17**:

> Major changes in the second edition included:
>
> - return without expression *not permitted* in function that returns a value (and vice versa)

Основные изменения во втором издании включали:

- возврат без выражения *не разрешён* в функции, которая возвращает значение (и наоборот)

---

Код без `return` :

```
if (n1 < 10)
    what(n1, n2 / 10);
if (n2 < 10)
    what(n1 / 10, n2);
what(n1 / 10, n2 / 10);
```

будет выполнять **обе** ветки, *(для ответа достаточно только одного прохода)* и ответ от этих функций будет просто *игнорироваться*. Дальнейший код `what(n1 / 10, n2 / 10);` с нулями аргументов приводит к плохому ответу и бесконечной рекурсии *(зацикливанию)*.